# Cannot call method 'then' of undefined - $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs

I use `$.ajax` in my angularjs controller to save an order. After I updated to AngularJS 1.2.2 i get the error `TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined` when `$.ajax` is called. I cannot find any information about that anything has changed. Am I doing something wrong? Here is my code for the ajax call:

```
$scope.saveOrder = function () {

  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: $scope.saveOrderUrl,
     data: $scope.order,
     async: false,
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (result) {
         $scope.order = result;
         $scope.isNewOrder = false;
         if ($scope.order.OrderId === 0) {
             alert("No order id was returned from the server. The order will not be opened in view mode.");
             window.location.href = appUrl + "/Order/Index/" + $scope.patientId;
         } else {
             window.location.href = appUrl + "/Order/Details/?personId=" + $scope.patientId + "&orderId=" + $scope.order.OrderId;
         }
     },
     error: function (xhr, status, error) {
         alert("Error when saving order. Status: " + status);
     }
 });
```

}

Comment: `then()` method is used on deferred/promise object. Seems to be used internally by angularJS(???). As async false is deprecated when used on deferred object, maybe your issue is here. As a first test, i'd remove `async:false,` and see if same error still appears. BTW, setting any ajax request to sync is generally (always?) a bad idea. Oh, and of course you should return promise i guess but i don't know in which context you are calling this code but maybe just : `return $.ajax({...})`

Comment: @A.Wolff Unfortunately it didn't help. I hava a function called saveOrder that calls the ajax code. I will update my question so that you see the whole function. I added the async: false parameter when we had the problem that the success method was called before the web api had returned the saved order.

Comment: you have tried `return $.ajax()`, right?! And adding async false just in order to wait a server response means you are not using ajax request correctly, you should code logic regarding retuned value inside any callback/promise method of the ajax object

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, I tried return $.ajax(). Do you have any example of how to use the ajax request correctly?

Comment: Unfortunately, i have no example of using ajax request **with** angularJS, i don't know enough this framework. I guess you'd have better to use specific method in angularJS regarding ajax, but like i said, i don't know it

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help anyway. I will continue to search for a solution. Maybe someone else knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.ajax` is jQuery's (or Angular's jQuery lite implementation) ajax method. To get Angular's Promises you need to use `$http` (note the absense of . after `$`)

Comment: I tried to use $http at first, but I got the problem that the success method was called before the web api had returned the saved order with the order id. Because of that I changed to $.ajax with async: true.

Comment: I changed back to $http and now it works like a charm. I do not know if our api has been changed or if it is something with angular or my code, but it works. Thanks for pointing be in that direction.